# Do Ruby instance variables have access modifiers?

Tags: ruby

So what I learned is that when I call a variable on an object e.g.

```
my_object.variable
```

A method called `variable` is returning the value of `variable`

```
def variable
   @variable
end
```

In Java, there are access modifiers. How can Ruby make use of access modifiers if getter methods are named after their variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there is a bit of terminology to clean up in the question before answering it.

One is that you never "call" variables. The Ruby expression

```
my_object.variable
```

is a *method call*. There is no such thing as a variable call. You call methods, not variables. Even if the method is named `variable`. :)

The second is if you did define the method like this

```
def variable
   @variable
end
```

either directly or by saying

```
attr_reader :variable
```

Then you have a method named `variable` and a variable named `@variable`.

Now to answer the question.

Ruby places access modifiers `public`, `protected`, and `private` on methods only, and *not* on variables. Access controls on variables don't really make sense, because they only be referenced within an object’s methods, and never with a prefix! In other words, you can never write this:

```
obj.@var
```

That's just a syntax error. You can write

```
obj.var
```

where `var` is the name of a method. And the access controls apply to that method only.

The fact that you may be making variables and methods with the same name (except for the `@`) actually doesn't matter. Only methods have access controls.

Hope that helps clear up some understandable confusion!

Comment: Thanks. Can I say "call variable" in Java when I do `my_object.variable`? I understand why I cannot in Ruby.

Comment: If you take "call" to mean "access" then yes, it will be understood by most people. But given that we generally speak of "function calls" and "method calls" it is probably best to avoid the term when speaking of variables. But people will understand you in Java, though I think "access" or "read" is better for variables. You call methods but read variables. As you noticed, you really can't say it in Ruby. :) Ruby and Java are indeed quite different here.

Comment: Technically speaking, instance variables belong to objects (aka instances), not classes. An instance variable can't be seen from a different *object*, not a different class. (E.g. it can be seen from a method in a subclass or superclass.)

Comment: Very true, and a worthy observation. I meant to say that you can’t _write_ code that refers to instance variables in the source code region outside of the class, but I could have found a better way to say that. I will rewrite the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to make a method private in Ruby.

Use `private` to make all later methods private:

```
class Foo
  def public_method
  end

private

  def private_method
  end
end
```

Or make a method private after you defined it:

```
class Foo
  def public_method
  end

  private :public_method # public_method is now private
end
```

Or - since the method definition returns a symbol too - this also works:

```
class Foo
  private def method_name
  end
end
```